# How to convert string into a decimal?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two strings "0.31" and "0.0076" and they need to be stored in a decimal(10,2) column in MySQL. How do I do this conversion in ruby but not in mysql directly

Comment: What should be stored for `"0.0076"`, `0.00` (truncated) or `0.01`(rounded)?

Comment: If you're using ActiveRecord then Rails probably wants to use BigDecimal objects for decimal columns. At least that's what it does with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 39):

try using `CAST`

```
SELECT CAST(colName AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM tableName
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe51d/1)

Answer (score 11):

use MySql conversion functions CAST or CONVERT . [Read Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

```
 Select CAST(columnName as DECIMAL(10,2))

                or

 Select CONVERT(columnName,DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: It looks like `CONVERT` allows literal string values where as `CAST` does not. However, `CONVERT` gives wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

OR you can do  the job like

```
select format(columnname, 0) as formated from tablename  where condition
```