# php pdo compare money value when column is varchar

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, type-conversion

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM salary_table WHERE "
. "ISNUMERIC(min_compensation) <= :name AND ISNUMERIC(max_compensation) => :name AND date_deleted IS NULL");
$stmt->bindValue(":name", ISNUMERIC($name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This is how i tried to compare if salary is between value. But i dont get the expected out put. I even got error.

> How to compare if values is with in range in php pdo

**`UPDATE`**

```
$name = floatval($_POST['name']);    
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM af_hris_masterfile_sss_table WHERE "
. "CAST(min_compensation AS float) <= :name AND CAST(max_compensation AS float) => :name AND date_deleted IS NULL");
$stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Getting :

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) <= '1000' AND CAST(max_compensation AS float) => '1000' AND date_deleted ' at line 1'

**`UPDATE`**

Tried this getting same error:

```
CONVERT(float,REPLACE(min_compensation,',','.')) <= :name AND CONVERT(float,REPLACE(max_compensation,',','.')) => :name
```

Comment: Have you tried `cast(min_compensation as decimal(8, 3))`?

Comment: @EhsanT can you provide it as answer?it worked for me

Comment: :) no need for answer, it has been already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7368178/1908331). You can up-vote that answer

Comment: you can explain why its `8,3` for future readers, also we need to close the OP @EhsanT

Comment: I just made something up for `8,3`. You can read the documentation of mysql decimal type [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html). But, in general, it's `DECIMAL(M,D)` where **M** is the first digit is  is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65 and **D** is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to a float in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368163/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-float-in-mysql)

Comment: maybe interesting? convert to decimal for money values?  [How to convert string into a decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245346/how-to-convert-string-into-a-decimal). Also: [Converting VARCHAR to DECIMAL values in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278733/converting-varchar-to-decimal-values-in-mysql).